# Import About Me property from AD

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-property

Is it possible to import from Active Directory a property for About Me ?
On the telephones tab exists a property Notes (I think it's called Info) but I can't import it.
Thank's

Comment: What do you mean you can't import it? Do you receive an error or message? Do you see it available in the User Profile Properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open ADSIEdit and open the properties of a user in your environment that has this information completed. Scroll down the list of properties until you find the one that has that information in it. Once you find it, look at the property name. It often is not what it is labeled in the ADUC forms. This is the name of the property you want. Once you have this information, then go to the User Profile Property and in the details of it, select that property as the source.